# Making Complex JSON Data Codable with Swift

Tags: swiftui, mocking, swiftui-previews

I know this isn't totally SwiftUI related but please bear with me.

Using this excellent video by Karin Prater https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHK5TwKwcE4

I have built an app using the spaceX API here : https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/launches using the same techniques as Karin.

I want to mock some data for previews. But I am stuck by the complexity of the returned data.

```
struct Launch: Codable, Identifiable {
    
    let links: Links?
    let success: Bool?
    let details: String?
    let name, dateUTC: String?
    let dateUnix: Int?
    let dateLocal: String?
    let launchLibraryID: String?
    let id: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
         case links
         case success,details
         case name
         case dateUTC = "date_utc"
         case dateUnix = "date_unix"
         case dateLocal = "date_local"
         case launchLibraryID = "launch_library_id"
         case id
     }

struct Links: Codable {
    let patch: Patch

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case patch
        
    }
}

// MARK: - Patch
struct Patch: Codable {
    let small, large: String?
}
```

Some example data returned with debug/print

```
SpaceX_API_Demo.Launch(links: Optional(SpaceX_API_Demo.Links(patch: SpaceX_API_Demo.Patch(small: Optional("https://images2.imgbox.com/94/f2/NN6Ph45r_o.png"), large: Optional("https://images2.imgbox.com/5b/02/QcxHUb5V_o.png")))), success: Optional(false), details: Optional("Engine failure at 33 seconds and loss of vehicle"), name: Optional("FalconSat"), dateUTC: Optional("2006-03-24T22:30:00.000Z"), dateUnix: Optional(1143239400), dateLocal: Optional("2006-03-25T10:30:00+12:00"), launchLibraryID: nil, id: "5eb87cd9ffd86e000604b32a"), SpaceX_API_Demo.Launch(links:
```

---

```
func successState() -> Launch {
    
    let launch = Launch(links: <#T##Links?#>, success: true, details: "", name: "", dateUTC: "", dateUnix: 1234567, dateLocal: "", launchLibraryID: "", id: "")
    
}
```

I have no idea how to fill the initializer for Links ...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

[Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) is a really helpful tool in these situations. When looking at the raw text in a web browser, it's almost impossible to tell what's what and not get bogged down in the complexity of `JSON`

in your example, you can take a look at what you have in the console of the `Postman` and begin implementing the keys.

[image: ss of postman]

Here, you can see you did not implement `reddit` and `flicker` keywords, so start with implementing these:

```
struct Links: Codable {
    let patch: Patch
    let reddit: Reddit
    let flickr: Flickr
}

struct Reddit : Codable {
   let campaign: String? // I am assuming that these are optional strings.
   let launch: String?
   let media : String?
   let recovery : String?
}

struct Flickr : Codable {
   let small : [String] // again, I AM ASSUMING it is a string (since it is empty in my console), but you have to learn what type these are by checking the documentation of your API
   let original : [String]
}
```

Also, you don't always have to specify `CodingKeys` enum everytime you create codable struct, `SwiftUI` automatically creates it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

See below for how I managed to correctly initialze "launch"

```
func successState() -> Launch {
    
    let links = Links(patch: Patch(small: "", large: ""), reddit: Reddit(campaign: "", launch: "", media: "", recovery: ""), flickr: Flickr(small: ["",""], original: ["",""]))
    
    let launch = Launch (links: links, success: true, details: "", name: "", dateUTC: "", dateUnix: 1234567, dateLocal: "", launchLibraryID: "", id: "")
    
    return launch
    
}
```